# Is there any cubic polynomial that does not touch $x$-axis?

Tags: polynomials

Let us consider the following cubic polynomials:

(i) $x^3-4x$, which touches the $x$-axis at three distinct points;

(ii) $x^3-x^2$, which touches the $x$-axis at two distinct points;

(iii) $x^3$, which touches the $x$-axis at single point.

Is it possible that a cubic polynomial never touches the $x$-axis?

Comment: In the first case, it doesn't ‘touch’ the $x$-axis, but intersects it at three distinct points. The second example, the curve touches the $x$-axis at the origin (which means this axis is the tangent at the origin) and intersects it at $x=1$.  Tou answer your question, it is impossible, because the limits at $\infty$ are $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ and we can apply the *intermediate values theorem*.

Answer (score 2):

Since, cubic polynomial must have atleast one real root(as, complex roots apears in pairs). It must go across the X- axis .

Comment: ‘Touch’ is not the proper term.

Comment: For me, you answer sounds like "it does not touch the x axis because it doesn't touch the x axis". I think your post would be better if you'd say *why* a cubic polynomial must have a real root.

Comment: @Jackozee Hakkiuz Hmm, I edit, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Consider $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and calculate $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$$. Finally apply intermediate value theorem.